# Just my code - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have enabled *Just My Code* in the debugging options, but it says it's for managed only.

When I have the debugger in the managed mode, it runs but closes straight after and I can't step into each line of code.

How can I make it work?

Comment: "The debugger runs and closes straight after"? Closes straight after what?

Comment: As soon as the debugger starts, it closes straight away before I can even see any of the windows at the bottom e.g locals etc. It better words, it starts and stops within seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Just My Code is enabled, it is possible to choose Break on the Debug menu and stop execution at a location where there is no My Code to display. When that happens, no code is displayed. Additionally, if you choose a Step command, it will take you to the next line of My Code.

First try to read *[How to: Step Into Just My Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)* and then will understand what they do.

As you're saying that debugger is not running, there might be many reasons:

1. You could type `Devenv.exe /SafeMode`, which starts Visual Studio in safe mode, loading only the default environment and services.
2. If it does not work, you could type `Devenv.exe /resetsettings`. It restores Visual Studio to default settings. Optionally, reset the settings to the specified `.vssettings` file.

   - [More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) about the Devenv.exe command line.
3. Switch other accounts or create a new account and try it again.
4. If it doesn’t work still, please uninstall Visual Studio via Add/Remove Program thoroughly and reinstall it again.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the just my code, but my debugger wont run as you can only use it in managed mode and my debugger for some reason wont run :( it just closes. Any ideas?

Comment: @sissons.h-Updated my answer check it and let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: I've tried safe mode and resetting the setting but no luck. Looks like I will have to reinstall it. Thank you for all of your help. I would rep you but as I'm new I can't do that yet.